# If we hear a noise long enough, is it going to settle as tinnitus?

Tags: acoustics

Some equipment sometimes have a high pitch ringing, and I was wondering out of curiosity:  can noises (not only drive you crazy but also) settle and become permanent ringing in your ear if you are exposed long enough?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about human perception. (Maybe try Biology stack exchange instead?)

Comment: +1 Perfect question! I was wondering this yesterday, never asked. Good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Tinnitus may occur as a result of prolonged exposure to high-amplitude sounds,  but I am not aware of any studies linking the perceived frequencies (in tinnitus) to the frequencies of the  sounds which preceded the onset.